# Difference between self.myString = string and self._myString = State(initialValue: string)?

Tags: swiftui, state

Given this context:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var myString: String
}
```

I first tried to initialize it this way:

```
init(_ string: String) {
    self.myString = string
}
```

But I got this error:

> Variable 'self.myString' used before being initialized

Then I did this:

```
init(_ string: String) {
    self._myString = State(initialValue: string)
}
```

It works fine, but since declarative programming and state are a new thing to me, I don't really understand the difference and what's going on here.

Comment: `State` is a property wrapper. About swift property wrappers read https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID617

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `@State var name: String` is a *property wrapper*, which is a nice wrapper around a variable called `_name` of type `State<String>`. Effectively, this:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var myString: String
}
```

translates to this:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    private var _myString: State<String>
    private var $myString: Binding<String> {
        _myString.projectedValue
    }
    private var myString: String {
        get { _myString.wrappedValue }
        set { _myString.wrappedValue = $0 }
    }
}
```

which should explain your problem (using `myString` before `_myString` is initialized).